# UIWebView embedded video fullscreen issue

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview, youtube-api

I'm using `ifame` api to embed youtube video into `UIWebView`. I have a problem when closing the fullscreen mode -  the player is translated to wrong position. Seems like the hide animation has some bug. The only solution i found is to place the `UIWebView` in top-left corner. I created a github repo with a simple project to demonstrate this issue.
https://github.com/demonoid67/youtube-video-sample . Can someone help me? Thanks in advangtage!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                NSString*  embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                                    <html>\
                                    <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                                    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>\
                                    <script type='text/javascript'>\
                                    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\
                                    {\
                                    ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})\
                                    }\
                                    function onPlayerReady(a)\
                                    { \
                                    a.target.playVideo(); \
                                    }\
                                    </script>\
                                    <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%f' height='%f' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1&controls=1' frameborder='0'>\
                                    </body>\
                                    </html>", youtubeWebView.frame.size.width, youtubeWebView.frame.size.height, selectedVideoModel.youtubeId];

            [youtubeWebView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
            [youtubeWebView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
            [youtubeWebView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL: nil];
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: thanks, but the bug with full screen is not fixed =(

Comment: Than what you have to do here is to add some constraints. :)

Comment: tried this approach and this even fixed the animation a little bit...not completely. But thank a lot this looks a lot better!